# Automated testing in CD

Tags: continuous-integration, automated-tests, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

What type of tests should be included in continuous integration?
Is it only unit tests or also integration/API, UI?
Or should integration/API and UI tests be included only in continuous deployment/delivery pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will largely depend on what you are trying to get out of your CI system and how long these test take to execute.  If it brings your CI agent down for an extended period you loose the benefits of having a CI system in place.

This leaves you with 3 options:

1. Run when launching a deployment.  If your organization has multiple deployment environments (e.g., dev, test, prod) to deploy to you can set these tests to only execute when being promoted to one of the more release ready environments.  This will allow you to continue to deploy to a dev or test environment for local testing.
2. Run these tests at a scheduled interval (e.g. over night).
3. Create a complex parallel build system where you compile and run your unit tests in one stage, and have a dedicated agent run the tests.  However, you could run into a situation where your tests are either queued for days or you have to pay several agents.